find the general solution the recurrence equation $b_n = 3b_{n-1} - b_{n-3}$
here are the steps I have done to try and find the general solution of this relation:
$$ b_n = 3b_{n-1} - b_{n-3}\\ = b^n = 3b^{n-1} - b^{n-3}$$
then divide by $b^{n-3}$ to get $$b^3 = 3b^2 - 1$$
then bring to other side $$b^3 - 3b^2 + 1 = 0$$
This is our characteristic equation.
However, now I am stuck because I cannot solve for $b$, which will be needed for the general solution. If anyone can help me solve this problem help it would be greatly appreciated
For a recurrence relation $a_n$ the general solution should be
$$ a_n = A_1a^n_1 + A_2a^n_2 + ... + A_ra^n_r $$
where $r$ is the number of roots for our characteristic equation.

What Will means is that it is unclear what you mean by "solve the recurrence." All those question marks are rude and smack of mockery, @WillJagy If you must post a one-word comment, there are other ways to do so which are not rude. I sometimes use ${}{}{}{}$

The question replaces subscripts by superscripts (powers) in the beginning of the calculation. Recurrence equations do not work that way.

i have made some edits to clarify the question. I am trying to get to the general solution. Also because this is a linear recurrence relation problem we can substitute a_n = a^n for each in the relation.

This is probably the best you can do with this method:  The general solution is $b_n = A_1a_1^n+A_2 a_2^n+A_3 a_3^n$, where $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are the three (real) zeros of $b^3-3b^2+1=0$.

And there are formulas for the zeros of a cubic, much like there is the quadratic formula for zeros of a quadratic, only the cubic is considerably more complicated. Said formulas are probably available on this here website, and certainly available in dozens of textbooks and on hundreds of other websites.

@GerryMyerson  ... but this is the casus irreducibilis, so the formula uses complex numbers to get the real solutions. So the formulas are probably not useful here.

This is an extremely special cubic, since the roots happen to be $\tfrac{1}{2}\sec\tfrac{2\pi}{9}$, $\tfrac{1}{2}\sec\tfrac{8\pi}{9}$, $\tfrac{1}{2}\sec\tfrac{14\pi}{9}$ (LMFDB).

As GEdgar points out, the solution is difficult and uses complex numbers. You could try the discriminant approach as shown here https://www.wikihow.com/Solve-a-Cubic-Equation  Good luck!

@GEd, for the casus irreducibilis, there is (as you know) a formula in terms of (real) trig functions. What is useful here, is hard to say, without knowing more about what use OP has in mind for the sequence.

The thing to keep in mind it is that the best solution to the recurrence is the symbolic one that keeps the symbols $a_1,a_2,a_3$ in the formulas until you need them. Later you can decide: Do I substitute using the cubic formula? Or using numerical methods?

As can be computed using this answer, the roots of $x^3-3x^2+1$ are $1+2\cos\left(\frac\pi9\right)$, $1+2\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}9\right)$, and $1+2\cos\left(\frac{13\pi}9\right)$.
